# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make a quiz with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
Now i'm trying to see if the jsonData works but i get this error message
but i can't find where the unecpected character is (it says line 1 column 2) but don't see it
Other thing am i doing it good?
I just started this year with coding

```
var jsonData = [
    {
        "q1": {
            "question": "what is the Capital city of Australia ",
            "answers": {
                "a": "Melbourne",
                "b": "Sydney",
                "c": "Caneberra",
                "d": "Brisbane"
            },
            "correctAnswers": "c"
        }
    },
]

const me = JSON.parse(jsonData)
console.log(me.correctAnswers);
```

Comment: **That's not JSON, it's JavaScript source code.** As a result, you don't use `JSON.parse` on it. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Also its an array so to access correctanswers: `jsonData[0].q1.correctAnswers`

Comment: ^^ or make it not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems have already been pointed out in the comments by [T.J Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) and [Samball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14246637/samball), but I wanted to show you the difference between a JavaScript data structure and a JSON string that needs to be parsed so you can better understand their comments.

- A JSON string needs to be parsed to JavaScript data structure (array, objects, values) for you to be able to work with the data stored in the file properly
- A JavaScript object/ array etc. that you define in JavaScript is already an JavaScript data structure so no need to parse it. Please note, any valid JSON is also valid JavaScript, but not the other way round.

Here a small program to illustrate what I've just written.

```js
// this needs to be parsed so you can access it as JS data structures
const stringData = `[
  {
      "q1": {
          "question": "what is the Capital city of Australia ",
          "answers": {
              "a": "Melbourne",
              "b": "Sydney",
              "c": "Caneberra",
              "d": "Brisbane"
          },
          "correctAnswers": "c"
      }
  }
]`;
// no need for this to be parsed, as it already is a JS data strucure (an array in this case)
const alreadyJavaScript = [
  {
      "q1": {
          "question": "what is the Capital city of Australia ",
          "answers": {
              "a": "Melbourne",
              "b": "Sydney",
              "c": "Caneberra",
              "d": "Brisbane"
          },
          "correctAnswers": "c"
      }
  }, // In JavaScript this comma is fine, in JSON it is not!
]

// parse string
const me = JSON.parse(stringData)

// now print both to see that they are in fact identical
// Keep in mind it's an array not an object!
console.log(me[0]); 
console.log(alreadyJavaScript[0])
```

> Note: While it is perfectly fine to put a `,` at the end of the last element in JavaScript, JSON does not allow that!